# How to test website in IE10 on windows 7?

Tags: testing, web, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

i need test website in IE10 on Windows 7. Is it even posible without installing windows 8 release preview?

thanks

Comment: Microsoft committed to a Windows 7 release of IE10 before it went RTM on Windows 8.  Since Windows 8 will go RTM (available to buy at retail) on October 26th... I'd expect that the Windows 7 version would appear before that date.  However Microsoft has gone silent on their IE Blog as of late, so I have my doubts they will meet their original commitment now. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/09/10/xss-trends-and-internet-explorer.aspx#10348388

Answer (score 1):

You may try a service like [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) if you need to test site's appearance only (there were few more like this but I can't remember now). Other option is to install Win8 on virtual machine and test it there. As far as I know IE10 is not available on Win7 (yet?).